# How do I install Laravel 6.x UI Components?

Tags: laravel

Laravel 6.x does come with UI components installed.

The commands I tried were:

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

but when I tried the first command, the following error occurred:

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir%2413f0252465cdc3c  
  27cde69055504a5a15fac72d5202de71c218bb397117734c7.json" file could not be d  
  ownloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servn  
  ame provided, or not known                                                   
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodena  
  me nor servname provided, or not known
```

What is the correct command(s) in order to install Laravel 6.x UI components?

Comment: Is this a fresh install?

Comment: I think this link will help you https://www.techiediaries.com/laravel-authentication-tutorial/ .

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with your internet, or packagist (composer default repository) is down.

Answer (score 3):

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui:auth
```

for more info you can see here https://laravel-news.com/running-make-auth-in-laravel-6

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue; the following command solved the problem for me for laravel "6.*"

```
composer require laravel/ui "^1.0" --dev
```